# Allowing user to stablish IP address using oscP5 with Processing Android

Tags: android, ip, processing

Hello fellow processing developers,

I'm using OSCP5 to link two processing sketches, one from an android device and the other in my computer, via WiFi.

I already tried it typing my computer's IP address directly on the new NetAddress that's on the setup() and it works just fine. However, I think it is best to give the user the chance to change the IP address of the computer to where the message is sent (it may change IP or change network and then the android app would not work).

I'm using a text field for the user to enter the IP address and then using this in a string called ipAddress that goes into the NetAddress that goes into the myRemoteLocation.

Here's my code (this goes on the phone):

```
import oscP5.*;
import netP5.*;

import apwidgets.*;

OscP5 oscP5;
NetAddress myRemoteLocation;

PWidgetContainer widgetContainer;
PEditText textField;
PButton button1;

PImage fondo;

boolean ValidIP = false;
String ipAddress = "192.168.0.107";

void setup() {
  size(480,800);
  smooth();

  fondo = loadImage("fondoAnd.jpg");

  widgetContainer = new PWidgetContainer(this);
  textField = new PEditText(10,40,380,120);
  button1 = new PButton(10,190,200,100,"Conectar");
  widgetContainer.addWidget(textField);
  widgetContainer.addWidget(button1);

  oscP5 = new OscP5(this,12000);
  myRemoteLocation = new NetAddress(ipAddress,12000);
}

void draw() {
  if (ValidIP == true){ 
    widgetContainer.hide();
    myRemoteLocation = new NetAddress(ipAddress,12000);
    background(fondo);
  }
  else if (ValidIP == false){
    background(0);
    textSize(20);
    text("Ingrese un IP válido",10,30);
    widgetContainer.show();
  }
}

void mousePressed(){
    OscMessage myMessage = new OscMessage("/test");
    myMessage.add(8);
    oscP5.send(myMessage, myRemoteLocation);
    println("enviomensaje"); //I print this in the console to know if it sends a message
}

void onClickWidget(PWidget widget){
  if(widget == button1){
    ipAddress = textField.getText();
    myRemoteLocation = new NetAddress(ipAddress,12000);
    ValidIP = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used OSCP5 for [a project](http://www.hirschandmann.com/2013/sony-xperia-z-time-slice/) with many Android devices as OSC clients and a computer as an OSC Server. I recommend starting with the [broadcast sample](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/oscP5/examples/oscP5broadcaster/oscP5broadcaster.pde). Notice the server listens for a "/server/connect" message from any ip on port 32000. This way you wouldn't need to hardcode the ip of the android device into the server, but at this stage you would still hardcode the ip of the server into the client android device.

The way I got around that limitation was by sending the "/server/connect" message to everyone("255.255.255.255") that would listen. Once the server connected an ip it would send a message back to the client. The client would then fetch the ip address from that message so it wouldn't need to send all subsequent messages to "255.255.255.255".

I've used the android SDK on the android devices and Processing on the computer, so my syntax will look different, but you should be able to understand the OSC part. Here is a simplified version:

```
package com.hirschandmann.updclient.network;

import netP5.NetAddress;
import oscP5.OscArgument;
import oscP5.OscEventListener;
import oscP5.OscMessage;
import oscP5.OscP5;
import oscP5.OscStatus;
import android.util.Log;

public class NetMan implements OscEventListener {

    public static final int PORT_IN = 12000;
    public static final int PORT_OUT = 32000;
    public static NetAddress SERVER;
    public static NetAddress EVERYTHING = new NetAddress("255.255.255.255",PORT_OUT);

    private static final String TAG = "NetMan";
    private OscP5 osc;

    public NetMan(){
        osc = new OscP5(this, PORT_IN);
    }
    public void oscEvent(OscMessage m) {
        String pattern = m.addrPattern();
        if(SERVER == null) {
            SERVER = new NetAddress(m.address().replace("/", ""), PORT_OUT);
            System.out.println(SERVER);
        }
    }
    public void connect(){
        Log.d("NetMan","connect");
        new ConnectTask().execute();
    }
    public void disconnect(){
        new DisconnectTask().execute();
    }
    @Override
    public void oscStatus(OscStatus status) {
        System.out.println(status);
    }
}
```

and the ConnectTask:

```
package com.hirschandmann.udpclient.network;

import netP5.NetAddress;
import oscP5.OscMessage;
import oscP5.OscP5;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        System.out.println("sending connect message: " + NetMan.PORT_OUT);
        OscMessage m = new OscMessage("/server/connect",new Object[0]);
        try{
            OscP5.flush(m,NetMan.SERVER != null ? NetMan.SERVER : NetMan.EVERYTHING);
        }catch(NullPointerException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        if(NetMan.SERVER != null) System.out.println("NetMan.SERVER: " + NetMan.SERVER);
        return null;
    }

}
```

So you should try the broacast sample on the computer and something like:

```
import netP5.*;

import apwidgets.*;

OscP5 oscP5;
NetAddress myRemoteLocation;

PWidgetContainer widgetContainer;
PEditText textField;
PButton button1;

PImage fondo;

boolean ValidIP = false;
String ipAddress = "255.255.255.255";

void setup() {
  size(480,800);
  smooth();

  fondo = loadImage("fondoAnd.jpg");

  widgetContainer = new PWidgetContainer(this);
  textField = new PEditText(10,40,380,120);
  button1 = new PButton(10,190,200,100,"Conectar");
  widgetContainer.addWidget(textField);
  widgetContainer.addWidget(button1);

  oscP5 = new OscP5(this,12000);
  myRemoteLocation = new NetAddress(ipAddress,12000);
}

void draw() {
  if (ValidIP == true){ 
    widgetContainer.hide();
    myRemoteLocation = new NetAddress(ipAddress,12000);
    background(fondo);
  }
  else if (ValidIP == false){
    background(0);
    textSize(20);
    text("Ingrese un IP válido",10,30);
    widgetContainer.show();
  }
}

void mousePressed(){
    OscMessage myMessage = new OscMessage("/server/connect");
    myMessage.add(8);
    oscP5.send(myMessage, myRemoteLocation);
    println("enviomensaje"); //I print this in the console to know if it sends a message
}

void onClickWidget(PWidget widget){
  if(widget == button1){
    ipAddress = textField.getText();
    myRemoteLocation = new NetAddress(ipAddress,12000);
    ValidIP = true;
  }
}
void oscEvent(OscMessage m) {
  String pattern = m.addrPattern();
  if(ipAddress.equals("255.255.255.255")) {
    ipAddress = m.address().replace("/", "");
    System.out.println("server is at: " + ipAddress);
  }
}
```

The above code isn't tested, but it should help.

Note that I've used OSC in UDP mode. There is also a TCP mode.
With UDP you can broacast to multiple ips but there is not guarantee your message
will get accross and each message is limited to a maximum of 64K of data.
Because there is no confirmation on UDP packets it's slightly faster than TCP.
With TCP, all packets are guaranteed to reach the other side, but with a cost to speed
and the lack of the broadcast ability. Also you can send more than 64K of data.
In my application I had to send 9MP and 12MP images so I've used both UDP and TCP:

- UDP to get the address of the server and send fast messages with
  minimal data
- TCP to transfer files: opened a tcp socket to send the data and closed it on transfer completion.

The other issue I encountered was the speed of wifi on Android. Wifi is handled differently on android devices than on a computer. The OS is tryig to preserve battery as much as possible, but that also means that if there is little activity on your device, Wifi will go into a low latency mode: it saves battery but it's super slow on connections, so if you need a fast response via OSC this is a problem. I [haven't found a proper solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029668/how-to-improve-local-wifi-speed-on-android) for the problem other than locking the wifi and power to be always on: trading battery life for a bit of Wifi responsiveness. I wish I knew the [solution to this problem](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46558/improving-local-wifi-speed). If you have any suggestions do share.

HTH

Comment: Thanks a lot! Still haven't tested but I'll let you know if it works. :D

Comment: Cool, feel free to tick/mark as you see fit. Also you might want to look at avahi or similar tools that might allow your networked devices to be accesed by a name rather than ip